# loading script to google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create new extensions but I'm having a problem when I include the JavaScript:

```
 {
  "name": "<name>",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "<description>",
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*.com"],
          "js": ["script.js"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "http://*.com/"
  ]
}
```

I'm having this error:

```
could not load extension from <path>
Invaild value for 'content_scripts[0].matches[0]':Empty path
```

Comment: Nice lorem ipsum in that example!

Comment: @Theodores Haha yeah... I was a kid 7 years ago

Answer (score 47):

You have a invalid `matches` URL - content script [match patterns](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns) need a *scheme*, *host*, and a *path*. The path includes the first slash `/` after the host (in this case, `*.co.il`).
Chrome is complaining that you do not have a path, so you have to add one.

- If you want to match **only** `http://*.co.il`, just change it to `http://*.co.il/`.
- If you want to match **all** paths change it to `http://*.co.il/*`.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. As a heads up, I noticed I had to add the "www" to the URL I wanted to match. A good rule of thumb is to simply copy and paste the URL you want to match and then proceed to repeat it with a `/*` on the end. Example for instagram: `"matches": [ "https://www.instagram.com/", "https://www.instagram.com/*"]`