# How do I disable a chrome extension for certain sites?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension that uses browser actions, as I want it to run on all sites, bar 1 (matching ".pannus." which is an internal dev site).

I can't work out how to achieve this, I have tried using the manifest and regex in PageStateMatcher.

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "...",
    "description": "...",
    "version": "0.0.2",
    "permissions": ["contextMenus", "declarativeContent"],
    "background": {
        "persistent": false,
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["content.js"],
        "css": [ "style.css" ]
    }],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": {
            ...
        }
    }, 
    "icons": {
      ...
    },
    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

If I add `"exclude_matches": ["*://*.pannus.*"],` here, I get an error:

`Invalid value for 'content_scripts[0].exclude_matches[0]': Empty path.`

I have also tried:

```
chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
        chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([{
            conditions: [
                new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
                    pageUrl: { 
                        schemes: ['https', 'http'],
                        urlMatches: '^((?!.pannus.).)*$'
                    },
                })
            ],
            actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction()]
        }]);
    });
```

But I get the error:

`Could not parse regular expression '^((?!.pannus.).)*$': invalid perl operator: (?!`

What is the best way to disable my chrome extension on certain sites? Or, failing that, not inject the extensions content script into the excluded hosts?

Comment: I don't want to block domains from loading, I want to block my extension from loading on certain domains

Comment: I get the same error: 
Invalid value for 'content_scripts[0].exclude_matches[0]': Empty path.

Comment: try `^(.*pannus)` as your regex.  I thin the problem is the regex engine syntax (re2) is slightly different than what you have.

Comment: https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax

Comment: I assume you mean in the urlMatches? I added:
`urlMatches: '^(.*pannus)'`
but the url https://dev.pannus.uk:4200/home still loads the extension fine

Comment: I couldn't get regex working so I added the full url to the excludes and that works for now

Comment: `urlMatches` uses RE2 syntax which doesn't support lookahead/behind assertions so [exclude_matches or globs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#matchAndGlob) is the correct solution indeed.

Comment: Apparently you can also use `urlContains: ".pannus."`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [loading script to google chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938891/loading-script-to-google-chrome-extension)

Comment: The error for `exclude_matches` is because you are missing the path component in your pattern. See the answer in the proposed duplicate.